# Gradle не может инициализировать виртуальную машину, так как не может зарезервировать достаточно места

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Андроид студия выдает такую ошибку:

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at         
https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1536000KB object heap
```

Встретил это только на windows и с libGDX. С обычными android проектами такого не было. На linux-е все работало. Возможно это из-за того что у меня свободного места на C только 500 мб. В любом случае, подскажите, как можно исправить. Заранее спасибо.